# Win32 Memory Mapped File With Views at Adjacent Locations

Tags: c++, c, c++11, winapi, visual-c++

I have a file that has multiple blocks in it.  I would like to map the file such that blocks that are not contiguous are contiguous in memory.

Example:

Assume chunk size is 1kiB.

- Chunk 1: Offset 0 in file, mapped to location X
- Chunk 2: Offset 1kiB in file, mapped to location X + 2kiB
- Chunk 3: Offset 2kiB in file, mapped to location X + 1kiB

I know that I can give suggestions to `MapViewOfFileEx` for a location to place the view.

I tried allocating address space using `VirtualAlloc` and then passing that as the base address (X), but it gives the error 487 - "Attempt to access invalid address."

How would I guarantee that there is a sufficiently large region in the address space such that I know that this will work?

---

As has been pointed out, views must be mapped at multiples of the memory allocation granularity, so 1kiB chunks would not work as desired.  Is it possible to make the example work if the chunk size is the same ass the memory allocation granularity?

Comment: "A pointer to the memory address in the calling process address space where mapping begins. **This must be a multiple of the system's memory allocation granularity**, or the function fails."

Comment: This won't work because you can't force Windows to map the file at any arbitrary address you choose.  But this is starting to sound like an X-Y problem.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: My reason for wanting to do this is so that I can allocate non-contiguous chunks of a file to an array of some data structure and then just use array indexing to write to the array and have it persist to the file.

Comment: Ok.  But why?  Why can't you allocate the array and then use `WriteFile` and `ReadFile` to save and load it?

Comment: I was looking at how SQLite's file is formatted.  It appears to be in pages (chunks in my terminology).  I was trying to figure out how to work like that and use memory mapped files.  The biggest difference is me wanting to have an array or such cross chunk boundaries.

Comment: @Graznarak what about using a wrapper class that has an overriden `operator[]` to access the appropriate block? You don't need to allocate sequential memory to use sequential indexing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are right.  My reason for wanting them to be sequential is that my expected access/processing pattern is linear, and having them sequential in the address space should have some slight improvement to cache performance...I think.

Comment: Note that the allocation granularity mentioned by Peter Ruderman is why sql server grows its files in 64kb chunks (that is the granularity on x86 and x64 systems, I don't know about others), sql server allocates 64kb at a time and uses that in 8kb extents.

Comment: SQLite's site indicates that pages are sized to powers of 2 between 0.5kiB and 64kiB.

Comment: It sure is a shame that Microsoft doesn't let you map over an address reserved (not committed) with VirtualAlloc.

Comment: @immibis: Of course that's possible. See [Address Windowing Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/memory/address-windowing-extensions), for example.

Comment: @IInspectable I can see in the documentation that AWE would allow for arranging memory pages in a desired order, but I cannot see how one would use it to place a memory mapped file in the address space.

Comment: I wasn't providing a solution to this question. I was commenting on immibis' statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  This idea won't work.  There are two problems.  First, the address you pass to `MapViewOfFileEx` is a request.  The system is under no obligation to map your file there and will fail if the address isn't free.  Second, the address you pass must be a multiple of the system's allocation granularity.  (Use the `GetSystemInfo` function to retrieve this value.)  You simply can't allocate virtual memory ranges that are only 1 KiB apart on any architecture I'm aware of.

**Edit**

If your heart is set on this, then I think the only (safe) way to do it is with an indirection layer.  Create a new class that stores a `vector` of pointers to the base address of each mapped region.  The class's `operator[]` will determine the correct block based on the index and calculate the address of the desired element within it.  (Basically the way a `std::deque` works.)